# //NonCompliant comment usage - SonarQube Custom Rule

Tags: sonarqube

I am trying to write a few SONARQUBE custom rules for my project.
After reading up the below document - 
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Writing+Custom+Java+Rules+101
and 
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples,
I created a custom rule like these classes below -

The Rule file:

```
@Rule(key = "MyAssertionRule")
public class FirstSonarCustomRule extends BaseTreeVisitor implements JavaFileScanner {

    private static final String DEFAULT_VALUE = "Inject";
    private JavaFileScannerContext context;
    /**
     * Name of the annotation to avoid. Value can be set by users in Quality
     * profiles. The key
     */
    @RuleProperty(defaultValue = DEFAULT_VALUE, description = "Name of the annotation to avoid, without the prefix @, for instance 'Override'")
    protected String name;

    @Override
    public void scanFile(JavaFileScannerContext context) {
        this.context = context;
        System.out.println(PrinterVisitor.print(context.getTree()));
        scan(context.getTree());
    }

    @Override
    public void visitMethod(MethodTree tree) {
        List<StatementTree> statements = tree.block().body();

        for (StatementTree statement : statements) {
            System.out.println("KIND IS " + statement.kind());
            if (statement.is(Kind.EXPRESSION_STATEMENT)) {
                if (statement.firstToken().text().equals("Assert")) {
                    System.out.println("ERROR");

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The Test class:

```
public class FirstSonarCustomRuleTest {

    @Test
    public void verify() {
        FirstSonarCustomRule f = new FirstSonarCustomRule();
        f.name = "ASSERTION";
        JavaCheckVerifier.verify("src/test/files/FirstSonarCustom.java", f);
    }
}
```

And finally - the `Test` file:

```
class FirstSonarCustom {

    int aField;

    public void methodToUseTestNgAssertions() {
        Assert.assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

The above Test file would later be my Project's source code.
As per the SONAR documentation - the // Noncompliant is a mandatory comment in my Test file. Thus my first question is should I add this comment everywhere in my Source code too?
If yes - is there any way I can avoid adding this comment, because I do not want to add that code refactoring exercise all over.

Can someone suggest me what I need to do here?

I am using SONARQUBE 6.3.

Answer (score 0):

This comment is only used by the test framework (`JavaCheckVerifier` class) to test the implementation of your rule. It is not mandatory in any way and for sure you don't need it in your real code.

Comment: Then how do we report an issue, if we do not use JavaCheckVerifier?

Comment: Issues are reported using `context.reportIssue` api, see example here https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-rules-examples/blob/master/java-custom-rules/src/main/java/org/sonar/samples/java/checks/AvoidAnnotationRule.java#L67